# scala play framework json conversion

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have two case classes A and B. I need to create Json object conditionally

1. Json.toJson(if (cond) A else B)
2. if (cond) Json.toJson(A) else Json.toJson(B)

Statement 1 does not compile but statement 2 does. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `toJson(...)` is:

```
 toJson[T](o: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): JsValue
```

That means that there must be an implicit `Writes` in scope for the type of argument `T`.

Now, the type of the *expression* `if (cond) A else B` is the *common super type* of the respective types of values A and B.

For types that don't explicitly inherit from the same base class the common super type will be Scala's `Any`. There is no implicit `Writes` for `Any` (because what is the JSON representation of anything?) so you'll get an "implicit not found" error at compile time.

On the other hand, each branch of the conditional in statement 2 evaluates to `JsValue`, so that is the value of the expression.